# Is there any command for calling a function in other function?

Tags: python-3.x

Here is my python code. I want to print the 1st function result in the 2nd function's print command in the bolded position. How can I do that?

```
def Position(self):
    if self.is_sitting == True:
        print ("sit down")
    else:
        print("stand up")

def introduce_person(self):

     print("The person name is "+ self.name,"." + 
           "\nThe person's personality is "+ 
           self.personality,".")   

     print("The person's position is " ,**self.Position()**)
```

Comment: To call a function from the same class use `self.functionName()`. Here it will be `self.Position()`.  However, if it is a static method, use `ClassName.function()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
class person:
    def __init__(self, *args):
        self.name, self.personality, self.is_sitting = args

    def Position(self):
        if self.is_sitting == True: 
            return "sit down"
        else: 
            return "stand up"

    def introduce_person(self): 
        print("The person name is "+ self.name,"." + "\nThe person's.  personality is "+ self.personality,".") 
        print("The person's position is " , self.Position())

obj=person('ali', 'ambitious', False)
obj.introduce_person()
```